# Как элегантно сбросить id'ы в таблице?

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим после удаления записи под номером 3 таблица имеет вид:

```
+-id-+--field--+
| 1  |  ...    |
+----+---------+
| 2  |  ...    |
+----+---------+
| 4  |  ...    |
+----+---------+
| .. |  ...    |
+----+---------+
```

Каким запросом можно сделать так, что бы id'ы опять были арифметической прогрессией с разностью один?

```
+-id-+--field--+
| 1  |  ...    |
+----+---------+
| 2  |  ...    |
+----+---------+
| 3  |  ...    |
+----+---------+
| .. |  ...    |
+----+---------+
```

Comment: Попробуйте это: [MySQL Delete all rows from table and reset Id to zero][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651867/mysql-delete-all-rows-from-table-and-reset-id-to-zero

Comment: @Aventus1, зачем вам это требуется?

Comment: А для чего?

Comment: @Etki, при выводе что бы номер соответствовал строке и не возникало путаницы

Comment: Если у вас возникает такая необходимость, то скорее всего неправильно спроектирована база данных и приложение. А вообще лучше это дело возложить на триггер.

Comment: На самом деле вам это не нужно. Если хотите список по порядку используйте программную переменную в качестве счетчика.

Comment: @Aventus1, автоинкрементный id это НЕ номер строки в выдаче. Это абсолютно разные сущности. Играясь с айдишниками, вы рискуете сломать больше, чем получить.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария.

---

автоинкрементный *id* это НЕ номер строки в выдаче. Это абсолютно разные сущности.

Играясь с айдишниками, вы рискуете сломать больше, чем получить.